# SpringMVC dropdown box displaying object information rather than values

Tags: java, spring

I have a model attribute set to a list of product objects. However when I try to access the list in a dropdown box form like this:

```
       <td><form:select path="product" items="${productList}"/></td>
```

It displays information about the object itself, rather than the product name:

```
Product@4c23d7e2
```

How can I make the form display the names of each element in productList, like? Like the first element would be

```
productList.get(0).getName()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to override the `toString()` method in Product as follows:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return getName();
}
```

Another would be to pass a `List<String>` of product names instead of `List<Product>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
<form:select path="product">
    <form:options items="${productList}" />
</form:select>
```

or

```
<form:select path="product">
   <c:forEach var="product" items="${productList}">
      <form:option value="${product.name}">${product.name}</form:options>
   </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

I have not tested. I think these will work.